# Does bash have a hook to determine when child shell exits?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tcsh

In `bash` I spin up a `t/csh` shell, which updates the tty input (`stty erase ^H`) in the .cshrc, but when `exit`-ing and returning to bash the <kbd>backspace</kbd> key no longer works.  This is because bash uses `readline` and I need to reset the erase (`stty erase ^?`).

If I understand `trap` correctly, it seems like I could trap the t/csh exit from within the t/csh process, and run commands after it exits.  However, my preference would be for the trapping to occur in bash, which ideally would detect a shell was called/exited and then run a script to reset its configurations.

This is preferred because I could call any number of shells (e.g., `dash`, `zsh`), which may inadvertently modify bash-specific settings.  Instead of maintaining multiple `trap` commands for each shell, it seems like it would be best to have one for bash.

---

Is my understanding of `trap` correct? If so, is it possible for `bash` to detect a child shell exit and then run a script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were on the right track with `trap`. What you want is the following:

```
trap "stty erase ^?" SIGCHLD
```

You can add that to `.bashrc`. Note that this will run when *any* subprocess ends.

This will only work in interactive sessions. For non-interactive sessions, `bash` [will not enable job control](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2001-04/msg00065.html) by default, so you will need to run `set -o monitor` first. But I doubt you'd need backspaces in non-interactive scripts.

[`SIGCHLD`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) is sent to the parent process whenever a subprocess exits.

---

An alternative method is to wrap your other shell in a script, such as:

```
#!/bin/sh
tcsh
stty erase ^?
```

Then, if you launch your shell through the script, the script will run the `stty erase` command after the shell exits. This is less likely to have side effects than a global `trap` handler, but of course it'll only work if you launch through the script every time (or create an alias to do so, e.g. `alias 'tcsh' '~/launch-tcsh.sh'`).

Comment: I suppose for tty settings, the job/control isn't as big a deal, but everything else that is probably a very important point.  My guess is there's a way to detect the child process and only do this trap if it's a different shell, but this is exactly what I was hoping for -- I was skeptical, but I'm glad I asked -- thank you!

Comment: @vol7ron Unfortunately, there isn't a foolproof way to detect what the child process was, from bash. You can use `jobs -n` to get recently exited jobs and hopefully the last one is correct, but there exists a race condition there. I think you might be better off using the script wrapper alternative instead.

Comment: I would have thought that the easiest way to enter `^?` is to type the `^` character then the `?` character: `stty` understands that the `^` character is a prefix for a control character.  Also, you could use the `Control-V` `Backspace` to tell Vim that you want to insert a literal Backspace character.

Comment: @AdrianPronk Thanks, didn't know `stty` did that. Had the vim literal one working at one point but then stuffed something up. Anyway, edited.